# C# MySQL Select all entries in table

Tags: c#, mysql

My code selects only first entry, but I'm need to select all entries in a table. Is there any way to do it? Thanks!

```
 public string getSiteForRotator()
    {
        string CommandText = "SELECT `url`, `desc`, `timer` FROM sites";
        string Connect = "connection_string";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader MyDataReader;
        MyDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (MyDataReader.Read())
        {
            string url = MyDataReader.GetString(0);
            string desc = MyDataReader.GetString(1);
            int timer = MyDataReader.GetInt32(2);
            return url+"," + desc+"," + timer.ToString();
        }
        MyDataReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
        return "ERROR";
    }
```

Comment: Did you notice that you have a return inside the while loop?

Comment: what do you think is the problem? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now your code return just the first record because in the while loop you exit the method at the first loop with the return that concatenates together the data from the first record. If you want to return all record then
the most simple way, is to use a DataTable

```
public DataTable getSiteForRotator()
{
    DataTable result = new DataTable();
    string CommandText = "SELECT `url`, `desc`, `timer` FROM sites";
    string Connect = "connection_string";
    using(MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect))
    using(MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(CommandText))
        da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

and in your calling code you could check if there are rows in the table and use that rows if there is any of them

```
DataTable result = getSiteForRotator();
if(result.Rows.Count == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No rows found");

else
    ... use the rows of the datatable ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public string getSiteForRotator()
    {
        string CommandText = "SELECT `url`, `desc`, `timer` FROM sites";
        string Connect = "connection_string";
        MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(Connect);
        MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(CommandText, myConnection);
        myConnection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader MyDataReader;
        MyDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        string url = "";
         while (MyDataReader.Read())
        {
            url = MyDataReader.GetString(0);
            string desc = MyDataReader.GetString(1);
            int timer = MyDataReader.GetInt32(2);
            url+"," + desc+"," + timer.ToString();
        }
        MyDataReader.Close();
        myConnection.Close();
        return url;
    }
```

Is This Helpfull ?? You use return statement in while loop, thats y it only shows single record.